# custom notification doesn't show up fully

Tags: android

> I have spent a day trying to solve this, the problem is that custom notification layout doesn't show up fully, looks like layout is cut. The code:

```
int pendingRequestCode = 0;
            int pendingFlag = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;

            RemoteViews layout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);

            Intent previousTrackIntent = new Intent();
            previousTrackIntent.setAction(PREVIOUS_TRACK_INTENT_FILTER);
            PendingIntent pendingIntentPreviousTrack = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), pendingRequestCode, previousTrackIntent, pendingFlag);
            layout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_previous,pendingIntentPreviousTrack);

            Intent pausePlayIntent = new Intent();
            pausePlayIntent.setAction(PAUSE_PLAY_INTENT_FILTER);
            PendingIntent pendingIntentPlay = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), pendingRequestCode, pausePlayIntent, pendingFlag);
            layout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_play,pendingIntentPlay);

            Intent nextTrackIntent = new Intent();
            nextTrackIntent.setAction(NEXT_TRACK_INTENT_FILTER);
            PendingIntent pendingIntentNext = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), pendingRequestCode, nextTrackIntent, pendingFlag);
            layout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_next,pendingIntentNext);


            Intent backToAppFromNotificationIntent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
            backToAppFromNotificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    backToAppFromNotificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendInt)
                    .setCustomBigContentView(layout);

            Notification not = builder.build();

            musicSrv.startForeground(1, not);
```

> The custom layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"

    >


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"
        android:id="@+id/notification_previous"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/play"
        android:id="@+id/notification_play"
        android:layout_weight="1.34" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_next"
        android:id="@+id/notification_next"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

> And the problem, notification layout simply doesn't show up fully:
>   [screenshot of emulator's screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTGDx.png)
>
> The result i expected:
>   [The planned result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upNUk.png)

Comment: can you try android:src instead of android:srcCompat?

Comment: i have removed it at all and now it works)))) thank you!